# MonoTouch.Dialog and limiting the number of rows

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, xamarin

I have a `MonoTouch.Dialog` with `UIViewElements` that contain a `UIWebView`.  This is a messaging type app and messages are constantly being added.  I can ealisy get **over 1000 `UIViewElements`** and there is no limit. Obviously memory is going to be an issue.

**What is the best way to only keep the last 100 rows?**

I need a **first in first out** type setup.   I can manually remove the `Elements` but do not know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you do have to do this manually. I used [TweetStation](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Jul-10.html) as an example.

Though this is not the latest app you can get (2010), it does cover a lot of the basics you need to understand.

[Here](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Jan-18.html) is more information on building custom cells, if you do not know already.

The core part of managing your list of elements is to override the `CreateSizingSource`-method on your inheriting `DialogViewController`-class and creating your own `SizingSource` as shown in [this part of TweetStation](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation/blob/master/TweetStation/UI/Timeline.cs).

I hope this will get you started.